# How to remove unnecessary cells without changing the location of the rest of the cells in the table?Without using css

Tags: html, html-table

> Blockquote I want to remove cells from table. I'm trying to learn how to merge table cells, but there is some rule of merging table cells that I don't know. Could you help me with that?No need use css i just need to make table looks without that cells Thanks

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr id="1">
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="4">
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
    <td colspan="4" rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="6">
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="7">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="8">
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="9">
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Here are the cells to remove]

[That link on jsfiddle where i marked cells that need remove or hide without using css](https://jsfiddle.net/vsfrut15/)

Comment: WHat do you mean by remove? display none?

Comment: Normally, complex structures like this are done with nested tables. Do you actually have data to match this layout?

Comment: i forget to say that i should not use css and i just need to make table looks without that cells

Comment: You are rowspan-ing and colspan-ing over numbers that are not there. You basically created that extra yourself. For example on #5 you have `colspan="4"` and there are no 4 columns, there are 3 columns... First time i see this btw...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3rfsbwg2/

Comment: Please put all information pertinent to your question _in your question_. It doesn't belong down here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like just an edit to your html...

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr id="1">
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="4">
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
    <td colspan="4" rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr id="6">
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>

  </tr>
  <tr id="7">
  </tr>
  <tr id="8">
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="9">
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it looks fine,thanks but why in #5 it is not visible that the cell is merged into 3 rows?